# TypeScript mapping over unboxed conditional: turn OR into AND

Tags: typescript

I have an array that contains multiple objects with functions `foo`.

Now I want to construct a new object signature with a function `foo` that inherits all signatures from the array item `foo` functions.

```
let arr = [
    { foo: (a: 'a') => 'A' as const },
    { foo: (a: 'b') => 'B' as const },
];

type MapAndUnion<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = { foo: T[number] extends { foo: infer V } ? V : never }

type U = MapAndUnion<typeof arr>
```

unfortunately, I am getting

```
type U = {
    foo: ((a: "a") => "A") | ((a: "b") => "B");
}
```

This is not callable, as the signatures are conflicting.

Is there a way to get (AND instead of OR)

```
type U = {
    foo: ((a: "a") => "A") & ((a: "b") => "B");
}
```

?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=33#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjEF4IG0BQEMQN4QGYHt8AuCACihIHIpKBKRAPgkoEFLoBnCAY3wDsOkAL4AadJhwFiZCswBGdRswBC7KF14DhYgLoBuVKjABPAA4gIAWSimWfACYBVPgEt+AHgAqEEAA8wIA5cAEogUPb8wMYscFDG7lB8xgxMSJKEJJ7IfACuALZyIDA6Pv6B9lzp0i58uEUQAGoQQhAA-I0QJHwgAG71QoYm5hCOiFY2dk6uHkMg+LjQcAyGmoIQviSjSAAMnNBJBquQUGO+pNR0ekA)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) in a [contravariant](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) position to get intersections instead of unions:

```
type MapAndIntersection<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>> =
  { foo: ((x: T[number]) => void) extends ((x: { foo: infer V }) => void) ? V : never }

type U = MapAndIntersection<typeof arr>
// type U = { foo: ((a: "a") => "A") & ((a: "b") => "B"); }
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjEF4IG0CwAoCEDeEBmA9gQFwQAUUpA5FFQJSIB8EVAgldAM4QDGBAdp0gBfADQYsuQiXKUWAI3pMWAIQ5RufQSPHoAugG4MGMAE8ADiAgBZKOdb8AJgEl+YEDE4geYAJYCAHgAVCBAAD3cnbgAlEChHAWBTVjgoUwCoflNGZgQJHHwiUjIyMNIg5H4AVwBbeQ89BgRmADcCX0cGcMjHbhKygulSX348DwgANQhhJtb2zogAfkmIUn4QFvHhY3QzSwgAVUQbOwcXNw8vH39+AL2QAjxoOEYMAHo3iHvD46ki8gopAARFAgbMIEDWGCIAAyAFyIHyaHNCEqMEGaY7CBAA)